# How to merge two data frame which has jumbled column names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 data frames df1 and df2 with the same column names but in different column numbers. How to merge as df3 without creating additional columns/rows.

```
df1

a  b  c
1  3  6

df2

b  c  a
5  6  1

expected df3

a  b  c
1  3  6
1  5  6
```

Tried below code but it did not work

```
df3=merge(df1, df2, by = "col.names")
```

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html Both cbind and rbind are on the same help page. You clearly need to read the parts about rbind.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `bind_rows` which automatically find the matching column names and if it is not there, it will add a `NA` row for those doesn't have.  The order of columns will be based on the order from the first dataset input in `bind_rows i.e. df1

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

-output

```
  a b c
1 1 3 6
2 1 5 6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = 1L, b = 3L, c = 6L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

df2 <- structure(list(b = 5L, c = 6L, a = 1L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: I am not able to bind them. getting error. """"""  Error: Can't combine `.."""""""

Comment: @Meenu do you have columns with different types in both datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange columns of any one dataframe according on another dataframe so both the columns have the same order of column names and then use `rbind`.

```
rbind(df1, df2[names(df1)])

#  a b c
#1 1 3 6
#2 1 5 6
```

In this case, using `rbind(df1, df2)` should work too.